# Converting XML tags to associative array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, xml, preg-match-all

I have following curl response

```
<status>success</status><statusmsg>online</statusmsg><vmstat>online</vmstat><hostname>my.server.com</hostname><ipaddress>XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX</ipaddress>
```

this is stored in `$data`

I tried converting it to an array like this

```
preg_match_all('/<(.*?)>([^<]+)</1>/i', $data, $match);
$result = array();
foreach ($match[1] as $x => $y)
{
$result[$y] = $match[2][$x];
}
```

But it doesn't work

> E_WARNING : type 2 -- preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '1' -- at
>   line 3

`$result` array is empty.

Comment: I have no knowledge of regular expression so what I did worked but I do not have a clue if it is ok:

`/<(.*?)>([^<]+)<\/.*>/i`

Please correct me if it is wrong

Comment: Using regex to parse XML will only lead to pain. Use an XML parser like [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your regex near the repeated group 1. You have to add a `\` before a repeated group. Also, escape the `/` for the closing tag.

Which gives you the following regex:

```
/<(.*?)>([^<]+)<\/\1>/i
```

Comment: This works great, simple and clear just as I like it. 

Output is beautiful:

`Array ( [status] => success [statusmsg] => online [vmstat] => online [hostname] => aurora.myserver.com [ipaddress] => XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX )`

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this answer as the solution so other users might find this as well. :)

Comment: Man don't you doubt I didn't click ✓ right away :)
SO won't let me for another minute. As soon it allow me I am gonna accept it

Comment: Note that you don't need the loop to get an associative array. You can just use `$result = array_combine($match[1], $match[2]);`

Answer (score 3):

Using Regex for parsing `HTML` or `XML` is not good approach instead use `DOMDocument`.

**Solution 1:** [**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/808898)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$string=<<<HTML
<status>success</status>
<statusmsg>online</statusmsg>
<vmstat>online</vmstat>
<hostname>my.server.com</hostname>
<ipaddress>XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX</ipaddress>
HTML;
;
$string="<root>".$string."</root>";
print_r((array)simplexml_load_string($string));
```

**Solution 2:**
[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/808898)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$string=<<<HTML
<status>success</status>
<statusmsg>online</statusmsg>
<vmstat>online</vmstat>
<hostname>my.server.com</hostname>
<ipaddress>XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX</ipaddress>
HTML;
;
$string="<root>".$string."</root>";
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadXML($string);
$domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$results = $domXPath->query("//root/*");
$data=array();
foreach($results as $result)
{
    if($result instanceof DOMElement)
    {
        $data[$result->tagName]=$result->nodeValue;
    }
}
print_r($data);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [status] => success
    [statusmsg] => online
    [vmstat] => online
    [hostname] => my.server.com
    [ipaddress] => XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
)
```

Comment: This is output that I want. But do I have to use DOM..... ? Please be aware that i do not control response i receive so there are no html tags only what I specified in my question.

Comment: @Luka Proper way of doing this is `DOM` instead of `Regex`. Prevent using `regex` for parsing `XML` or `HTML` , might you got stuck in future if you have multiple attributes, nested tags etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't really care to check that the starting and ending tags match, this will pull out the data inside each tag and place it into the array `$result`. (It's not clear from your question what output you want.)

```
preg_match_all('/<(?:.*?)>([^<]+)<(?:.*?)>/i', $data, $result);
```

Note that starting a group with `(?:` instead of just `(` just means that the group won't be included in the result (this is referred to as a *non-capturing* group).

**Edit**

Given that you want an associative array, you can do the following:

```
preg_match_all('/<(.*?)>([^<]+)<\/\1>/i', $data, $match);
$result = array_combine($match[1], $match[2]);
```

The loop to collect the results is unnecessary.

Comment: On example while using `$result["status"]` i want to get contents of `<status>` tag

Answer (score 1):

For optimization purpose, please consider eager "modifiers"

```
/<([^>]+)>([^<]+)?<\/\1>/i
```

From my point of view, capturing first element is important because you would be sure to deal with real XML

```
<foo>bar</foo>
```

and not

```
<foo>bar</superman>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that any of the other regex-based solutions bothered to completely iron-out the pattern.

- Your first capture group should be using a negated character class `([^>]+)`, your second capture group does this properly.
- There is no need to use the `i` modifier at the end of your pattern because there are no alphabetical characters in the pattern.
- The text between each tag *could* be empty, so it is important to use `*` instead of `+`.  This will ensure that there is always a matching pair of elements for `array_combine()` to use.
- In the event that `preg_match_all()` returns a `false` result, it is important to check that before calling `array_combine()` to avoid getting a WARNING message.
- As Michael Mior stated, `array_combine()` is the most direct/appropriate way to merge the `[1]` and `[2]` match subarrays.

Method ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/876dd802caf3a0139f2f0b08a72b914460505c6f)):

```
$data='<empty></empty><status>success</status><statusmsg>online</statusmsg><vmstat>online</vmstat><hostname>my.server.com</hostname><ipaddress>XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX</ipaddress>';
$result=preg_match_all('/<([^>]+)>([^<]*)<\/\1>/',$data,$out)?array_combine($out[1],$out[2]):[];
var_export($result);
```

> Note: my pattern will process your original sample input in just 65 "steps" compared to jarodev's 141-step pattern.  Please use my more efficient pattern in your project.

Output:

```
array (
  'empty' => '',
  'status' => 'success',
  'statusmsg' => 'online',
  'vmstat' => 'online',
  'hostname' => 'my.server.com',
  'ipaddress' => 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/de/function.simplexml-load-string.php) function.

Comment: I am focused on fixing regular expression.

Comment: @Luka Then ask correctly instead of down voting a solution ;)

Comment: @YaennuuH I'm the one who down-voted because this is not a solution. You just gave a function without solving the problem. Also, there's no root element in the XML fragment, so `simplexml_load_string` won't work as-is anyway.

Comment: alright, therefore sorry Luka. @Michael Mior then it's a way better solution to add the root elements instead of using a regex ;) And I gave a link to the function page from PHP so he could read and understand how it works.

Comment: @YaennuuH See this discussion on Meta for an explanation of why link-only answers should be avoided https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers